# How to connect to port 1433 for accessing mysql database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run a rails server for an web application (working collaboratively and pulling code from GitHub).

Relatively new to mysql and rails and I keep getting this error when I go to http://localhost:3000/ using an IDEE (cloud9)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdY3Q.png

1.) Someone told me I should try opening my 1433 in OS X firewall, which I believe I did by following these steps http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-open-specific-ports-in-os-x-1010-firewall-3616405/

However when I run "telnet localhost 1433" on my command line to check if the port is open, it says "Connection refused".

2.) I also ran "mysql -u USERNAME -p" on the command line and typed in the password for access to the database and it returned: "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ktha'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses port 3306 by default.
1433 is SQL server default port